# How to make nodejs cassandra driver work in Lambda?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, aws-lambda, datastax

Lambda not returning the callback function if I'm not closing the connection but if I do close the connection the second time the function not working and I'm getting error:
"Connecting after shutdown is not supported"
The code:

```
client.connect(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1';
  client.execute(query, [], {}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("there was an err");
      console.log(err);
      process.exit();
    }
    else
    {
      client.shutdown(function() {
        callback(null, {});
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I know that it's the way it should work by:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/latest/faq/#should-i-shut-down-the-pool-after-executing-a-query

But is there any solution to manage the connection on Lambda?

More info on Lambda here container reuse:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Comment: Set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` inside the handler.  Otherwise the callback fires but the function times out instead of returning a result.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/46061612/1695906.

Comment: Some background on the driver: When `client.connect()` is called the first time, it will initialize the pool to each host selected by the load balancing policy (local nodes by default). The following times you call `client.connect()` it will be a no-op.
In an application were you control the startup and shutdown, you should call `client.connect()` once during startup and `client.shutdown()` when shutting down the app. Outside a controlled application shutdown, you should never call `client.shutdown()`.
In your case, the idea would be to reuse the `client` instance when possible.